# Zoom to Postcode QGIS Plugin - "Postcode not Found"

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to get the Zoom to Postcode plugin for QGIS to work on my machine (Mavericks, QGIS 2.2.0)

The plugin downloads fine, and when I first try to search for a postcode it alerts me that it needs to download the postcode data, which I approve.

The loading dialog box appears and seems to complete OK.

Has anyone else had this problem? Maybe I can download the file someplace else and manually include it.

Comment: Looking into the source code, I managed to find the download target and now have the downloaded .pkl files ready to go...I think I just need to find the right place to put them

Comment: Ok - I found the location but sure enough the .pkl files are there and they all look good. Opened one up in a text editor and searched for the postcodes I'm trying with and they are there too - so I'm totally at a loss as to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.

The path was wrong, as it was looking for a file 'directory\file' when it needed to look for 'directory/file'

If you're trying to use this plugin on a Mac, go to the plugin folder, and open zoomtopostcode.py in a plain text editor.

Change line 168 from

```
find_pkl = str("UK_Postcodes\\" + input_pcode[:2] + ".pkl")
```

to

```
find_pkl = str("UK_Postcodes//" + input_pcode[:2] + ".pkl")
```

Hopefully it will now work for you.